# Visual Studio Codes PHP extensions and Virtual Box

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

On my Windows 7 workstation, I've installed a VirtualBox VM with a Linux,Apache,MySql,PHP (LAMP) installation. I've also installed Visual Studio Code editor in Windows and edit the PHP code via a shared folder in VirtualBox. The Visual Studio Code PHP extensions (Intellisense, Xdebug) are wanting a 'path' to the PHP install. Is there a way to point these extensions to the VirtualBox PHP install, or do I have to install a second PHP install on my Windows machine as well, and then point Code to this install? I'm hoping not, but wanted to confirm.